# SQL- Selecting the most similar product

Tags: mysql, sql

Alright, I have a relation which stores two keys, a product Id and an attribute Id. I want to figure out which product is most similar to a given product. (Attributes are actually numbers but it makes the example more confusing so they have been changed to letters to simplify the visual representation.)

Prod_att

```
Product | Attributes  
   1   |    A     
   1   |    B  
   1   |    C  
   2   |    A  
   2   |    B  
   2   |    D  
   3   |    A  
   3   |    E  
   4   |    A
```

Initially this seems fairly simple, just select the attributes that a product has and then count the number of attributes per product that are shared. The result of this is then compared to the number of attributes a product has and I can see how similar two products are. This works for products with a large number of attributes relative to their compared products, but issues arise when products have very few attributes. For example product 3 will have a tie for almost every other product (as A is very common).

```
SELECT Product, count(Attributes)  
FROM Prod_att  
WHERE Attributes IN  
(SELECT Attributes  
FROM prod_att  
WHERE Product = 1)  
GROUP BY Product
;
```

Any suggestions on how to fix this or improvements to my current query?
Thanks!

*edit: Product 4 will return count() =1 for all Products. I would like to show Product 3 is more similar as it has fewer differing attributes.

Comment: How about defining a minimum set of similar attributes? This can be achieved using a `HAVING` clause.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/384276/how-to-create-search-engines-like-google

Comment: What [RDBMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database_management_system) you are using? `RDBMS` stands for *Relational Database Management System*. `RDBMS is the basis for SQL`, and for all modern database systems like MS SQL Server, IBM DB2, Oracle, MySQL, etc...
Can you also give sample records with your desired result?

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: You want to return the row(s) with the highest number of matching attributes?

Comment: How *should* Product 3 be treated in this case? It sounds like you need some sort of additional factor to discount similarity for products with few attributes... but that's hard to suggest without knowing what outcome you want.

Comment: I edited the post to include the preferred response. My original question didn't have a good answer for Product 3, so I added 4 (which is more clear).

Comment: @JW웃 I'm using MySQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT 
  a_product_id, 
  COALESCE( b_product_id, 'no_matchs_found' ) AS closest_product_match
FROM (
  SELECT 
    *,  
    @row_num := IF(@prev_value=A_product_id,@row_num+1,1) AS row_num,
    @prev_value := a_product_id
  FROM 
    (SELECT @prev_value := 0) r
    JOIN (
        SELECT 
         a.product_id as a_product_id,
         b.product_id as b_product_id,
         count( distinct b.Attributes ),
         count( distinct b2.Attributes ) as total_products
        FROM
          products a
          LEFT JOIN products b ON ( a.Attributes = b.Attributes AND a.product_id <> b.product_id )
          LEFT JOIN products b2 ON ( b2.product_id = b.product_id )
       /*WHERE */
         /*  a.product_id = 3 */
        GROUP BY
         a.product_id,
         b.product_id
        ORDER BY 
          1, 3 desc, 4
  ) t
) t2 
WHERE 
  row_num = 1
```

The above `query` gets the `closest matches` for all the products, you can include the `product_id` in the innermost query, to get the results for a particular `product_id`, I have used `LEFT JOIN` so that even if a `product` has no matches, its displayed

[**SQLFIDDLE**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e1ff6/30)

Hope this helps

Comment: Works great! Significantly more complex than just comparing the matching attributes. Thanks.

Comment: nice to know its helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

Try the ["Lower bound of Wilson score confidence interval for a Bernoulli parameter"](http://www.evanmiller.org/how-not-to-sort-by-average-rating.html). This explicitly deals with the problem of statistical confidence when you have small n.  It looks like a lot of math, but actually this is about the minimum amount of math you need to do this sort of thing right.  And the website explains it pretty well.

This assumes it is possible to make the step from positive / negative scoring to your problem of matching / not matching attributes.

Here's an example for positive and negative scoring and 95% CL:

```
SELECT widget_id, ((positive + 1.9208) / (positive + negative) - 
1.96 * SQRT((positive * negative) / (positive + negative) + 0.9604) / 
(positive + negative)) / (1 + 3.8416 / (positive + negative)) 
AS ci_lower_bound FROM widgets WHERE positive + negative > 0 
ORDER BY ci_lower_bound DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could write a little view that will give you the total shared attributes between two products.

```
create view vw_shared_attributes as
select a.product, 
      b.product 'product_match', 
      count(*) 'shared_attributes'
from  your_table a
  inner join test b on b.attribute = a.attribute and b.product <> a.product
group by a.product, b.product
```

and then use that view to select the top match.

```
   select product,
      (select top 1 s.product_match from vw_shared_attributes s where t.product = s.product order by s.shared_attributes desc)
    from your_table t
    group by product
```

See http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/53039/1 for an example