# MySQL Cross Reference Different Products

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

I'd design a Table Schema and query for searching products that are similar but have different number. This design is not good for hundred or thousand of products.

I would like to search products that are similar.

```
Product A -> Product B
Product A -> Product C
```

**-> means Product X is the same as Product Y**

When I found products for Product A is not problem, but how could I design the query/table if I want to find products that fit for Product B, C or D?

This is my two tables

**t articles**

```
id | text
 1 | Product A
 2 | Product B
 3 | Product C
 4 | Product D
```

For better understanding, I'm going to use text instead of id.
In my real table there's ids on it.

**t cross reference products**

```
id_1 | id_2
  A  |  B
  A  |  C
  A  |  D
  B  |  A
  B  |  C
  B  |  D
  C  |  A
  C  |  B
  C  |  D
  D  |  A
  D  |  B
  D  |  C
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's wrong with what you have? That's the normal way to represent a many-to-many relationship.

Comment: Are you bothered that you have to have both `A -> B` and `B -> A`?

Comment: possible a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16445993/sql-selecting-the-most-similar-product/16447846#16447846

Comment: My main concern if this type of relationship could slow the speed of my queries due to a huge amount of same data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't look like a duplicate of [SQL- Selecting the most similar product](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16445993/sql-selecting-the-most-similar-product/16447846#16447846) to me.  The issue isn't how to find the closest match but how to design tables of related data.

What does it mean for A to the same as B.  I think that you are going to need to give more detail to get a good answer.

If A, B & C are all the same because they all belong to type "foo" then I think that it'd be best to add a "type" column:

```
id | type | text
1  | foo  | A
2  | foo  | B
3  | foo  | C
4  | bar  | D
```

Then you can easily find all of the things of type foo.

If you really need to represent a many-to-many relationship then use an intersection table like you suggested.  As long as you index id_1 and id_2 (and id from your t articles) performance should be just fine.  Hundreds or thousands of rows really isn't very much for mysql.